# Read_xml not retrieving correct data in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, xml

I have this xml dataset: https://www.kaggle.com/datasets/tiredlikedog/3m-xml
from which I want to retrieve Product classification ETIM and Product identification number.

I am new to xml, I thought by applying

```
df = pd.read_xml('/kaggle/input/3m-xml/ProductData.xml')
```

I would get the data but the results seem not OK:

[image]

Do you know how to change it to retrieve the data?

I also changes the dataset to this: https://www.kaggle.com/datasets/tiredlikedog/test-xml

and now i get these data

[image]

I think something is off with the format...
Please could you help me?

Answer (score 0):

```
# supply kaggle username / API key for authentication
import os

os.environ['KAGGLE_USERNAME'] = "username"
os.environ['KAGGLE_KEY'] = "API_KEY"

import kaggle

kaggle.api.authenticate()

# download dataset: please note, that you need to provide username along with the dataset name
kaggle.api.dataset_download_files(dataset='tiredlikedog/3m-xml', unzip=True)

# read XML using pandas
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_xml('ProductData.xml')

df
```

Custom parsing (using lxml):

```
from lxml import etree
from collections import defaultdict

ns = {
  "ns": "http://www.ketenstandaard.nl/productgegevens/SALES/005.1"
}

data = defaultdict(list)

root = etree.parse('ProductData.xml')

lines = root.xpath('//ns:ProductLine', namespaces = ns)

for line in lines:
  data['LineNumber'].append(line.findtext('./ns:LineNumber', namespaces = ns))
  data['StatusCode'].append(line.findtext('./ns:StatusCode', namespaces = ns))
  data['ManufacturersProductId'].append(line.findtext('.//ns:ManufacturersProductId', namespaces = ns))
  data['InternationalProductClassCode'].append(line.findtext('.//ns:InternationalProductClassCode', namespaces = ns))

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

df
```

Comment: Hi Alexandra, I dont think it works... I it nested xml and it doesnt show any data... Please, any other idea how to get this running? thanks!

Comment: Hi, and what fields would you like to have in the dataframe?

Comment: Hi, I want to export these 2 ManufacturersProductId and InternationalProductClassCode ... I managed to do so in this way

```
product = []
for description in root.iter('ManufacturersProductId'):
    #print(description.text)
    product.append([description, description.text])

etim = []
for description in root.iter('InternationalProductClassCode'):
    #print(description.text)
    etim.append([description, description.text])
    ```

But I have no clue how to join product ID to ETIM...

Comment: Added example of parsing using lxml library